# How To fetch Part of Json from another Json Using Shell Script or Python

Tags: python-3.x, shell

Can anyone help me to fetch specific part from the below JSON using python or shell script or convert this Json into Flat file

Required Fields: Id, attributes in another Json

{
"data": {
"type": "abc",
"id": 1,
"attributes": {
"accountName": null,
"addedAt": null,
"addressCity": null,
"addressCountry": null,
"addressState": null,
"addressStreet": null,
"clickCount": 0,
"contactHistogram": [
[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0],
[0, 0]
],
"websiteUrl3": null,
},
"relationships": {
"account": {
"data": {
"type": "account",
"id": 1
}
},
"updater": {
"data": {
"type": "user",
"id": 1
}
}
},
"links": {
"self": "https://github.com"
}
}
}

Tried multiple ways to extract few columns from JSON and converted to Flat file using python but flat file created is not as expected

Comment: l=  jSON 

for i,v in l.items():
          if(i!="relationships"):
             print(i,v)
This wont work

Comment: `jq` tells me `parse error: Expected another key-value pair …` after `"websiteUrl3": null, `.

Answer (score 0):

read -m json j < file.json &&
print -r -- "${j.data.attributes}"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).